# SaveChanges(): "...can only appear on the left hand..."

Tags: entity-framework

I have this piece of code:

```
Schedule chk = _entities.Schedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleStart == schedule.ScheduleStart && x.ScheduleEnd <= schedule.ScheduleEnd).FirstOrDefault();

if (chk != null)
{
     chk.Discontinued = true;
     _entities.SavingChanges();
}
```

basically if something exists in database with that criteria, set discontinued = true and save...

but I get this error:

**The event 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SavingChanges' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=**

What is wrong?

/M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the wrong method. `SavingChanges` is an event, not a method. You want `SaveChanges`, instead.